# Editing a starred post in chat breaks display for user who starred it

Tags: bug, status-completed, chat, chat-stars

Steps to reproduce:

- User A posts a message
- User B stars it, the star next to the post appears yellow
- User A edits the post
- The display of the star in User B's view becomes black, as if they haven't starred it

This is the worst bug ever in the history of StackExchange and makes the entire network completely unusable for me. I'm going to Yahoo! Answers until this is fixed.

Comment: If you can cope with Yahoo Answers, more power to you!

Comment: **Worst bug ever!** agreed. I'm going to IRC

Comment: Is only the display affected, or is it practically unstarred?

Comment: Good luck on Yahoo! Answers. I'm quitting the internet all together, this was the final straw.

Comment: @Bart No the star score remains the same, but the display is inversed, so clicking again removes the star from the score but the star turns yellow. If it is the only star, removing it and adding it again fixes it (i.e. if the score gets to zero the display is reset). The right panel is not affected. Should be a simple fix (pseudo) `var isStarredByMe = postIsStarredByMe(post);` before the DOM is updated, and then restore the display based on that flag afterwards. I know from bitter experience that a lot of the DOM is outright replaced when a post is edited, rather than updating the content.

Comment: @DavidX.Random Ah okay. Then I have to applaud you for your understatement regarding the severity of this particular bug.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is fixed now, editing events will no longer overwrite the star displays. You can come back from Yahoo! Answers.