# Chat stars not appearing next to my own starred messages

Tags: bug, status-completed, chat, chat-stars

Since sometime earlier today (that I noticed, anyway), when someone stars a comment I make in chat, it's not displaying the star next to the comment in the main chat window.

The stars are appearing next to everyone else's comments, and if I refresh the window manually, they appear where I expect. But they aren't showing up automatically for my own message.

I don't seem to be the only person to have noticed this problem.

Comment: Honestly, all of chat has been really slow for me lately. Things take forever to load, like the page, one boxes, stars. Sometimes they wouldn't load at all

Comment: i also had to refresh to get the winter bash hats, but the odd thing about the stars is that other user's starred comments are working fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Fixed now, thanks.

To fix [this bug](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/271632/115866) I stopped overwriting the star indicator when a message is edited; unfortunately in some cases – namely, when you yourself post a new message – this also prevented said star indicator from being created in the first place. The chat client was trying hard to show the stars you received, it just didn't have anywhere to put them.

The fix is deployed; it's a client-side change, thus needs a refresh for currently-open chat tabs.